# Concatenate two columns based upon another column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, concatenation

I have database as follows

```
A     B
1   ereee
2   ereee
2   sdfsd
3   nere
1   sdfsd
```

I want to have a data which will be as follows

```
A     B
1   ereee,sdfsd
2   ereee,sdfsd
3   nere
```

what is the query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Your question didn't specify what kind of database. The following works for MySQL and perhaps a few others:

> **GROUP_CONCAT(expr)**
>   This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT A, GROUP_CONCAT(B SEPARATOR ',') AS B 
FROM table
GROUP BY A
```

### Update 2015-07-30 09:43 +0000

Since it's been made clear that this is about SQL Server 2005, the question might be a duplicate of this:

[Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: Sorry, the database is SQL Server 2005